# Match group in MySQL query with regex containing some words but not others

Tags: mysql, regex

I am querying against a database of songs, and want to separate out rows containing the song "Tube" (which may appear with any number of characters before and after it, e.g. "Track 01. Tube -> Another song"), but not match the songs "First Tube" or "Last Tube", which may have extraneous characters as well.

I've been doing this with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `songs` WHERE `song` LIKE ('%Tube%') and song not like ('%first%') and song not like ('%last%');
```

But would prefer to use a regular expression so that I may use the same matching in other places (like within PHP code).

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE song REGEXP '.*(first|last){0}.*(tube).*';
```

But it didn't work obviously, it matches 'First Tube' songs too.

Comment: Honestly I don't think you want to use `REGEXP` unless you have to (which you don't). `REGEXP` is probably the most limited Regex flavor that exists.

Comment: Thanks for offering to help. You are right that I don't have to (my code is working with `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE`s strung together), but I want to use a single regular expression so I can re-use the pattern matching outside of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expressions here, I think you might be looking for a regular expression more along these lines:

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE song REGEXP ".*Tube.*" and NOT REGEXP ".*first.*|.*last.*"
```

That's not far from the `LIKE` statements you have above, but it would give you a start.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The reason I want to use regular expressions is that I'd like to use the same ones to match things outside of mysql where i can't simply say "and NOT" ...

Comment: I see. Regular expressions can be super powerful, although they definitely have limitations within mysql. Best of luck.